# C# - Find Number in String and Add a Value

Tags: c#, string, textbox, split, addition

I have a file that looks like this:

```
R.D.    P.N.      X       Y        Rot  Pkg
L5      120910    64.770  98.425   180  SOP8
L4      120911   -69.850  98.425   180  SOIC12
L10     120911   -19.685  83.820   180  SOIC10
L9      120911    25.400  83.820   180  0603
L5      120910    62.484  98.425   180  SOP8
```

And I have two text boxes labled `Xinput` and `Yinput`. From these text boxes the user enters values into them. Once the values are entered and the user clicks "GO" then I would like to take the string from the file and add the `Xinput` value to the `X` column and the `Yinput` value to the `Y` column from the file.

---

*WHAT I MEAN...*

So if the user inputs **"10.552"** into the `Xinput` textbox and **"-140.123"** into the `Yinput` textbox, the new data would look like this:

```
R.D.  P.N.      X       Y         Rot  Pkg
L5    120910    75.322  -41.698   180  SOP8
L4    120911   -59.298  -41.698   180  SOIC12
L10   120911   -9.133   -56.303   180  SOIC10
L9    120911    35.952  -56.303   180  0603
L5    120910    73.036  -41.698   180  SOP8
```

---

***QUESTIONS:***

- Is this possible to do?
- How would I go about doing this if it is possible?

Comment: Which data structure represents a table you have shown above? is it multi dimension array, DataTable, what?

Comment: It is just a .txt file. I was thinking about using the `string.Split()` but I am not so sure about how to go about that..

Comment: Is it large file? How many rows?

Comment: Does the file use fixed-width columns
?

Comment: @Polishchuck: The file has no set length (rows) there... agent-j: There is a tab or a space delimiter between each column and there are always 6 columns

Comment: Are these columns always a fixed width or are they separated by tab characters? never mind you answered as I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, I don't have your file so this is a best guess. I'm sure I didn't leave out much. I know it seems overkill, but you really have full control over each value in your data this way.

```
public class ComponentLocation
        {
            public string ReferenceDesignator { get; set; }

            public string PartNumber { get; set; }

            public double xValue { get; set; }

            public double yValue { get; set; }

            public int Rotation { get; set; }

            public string Package { get; set; }

        }

        public IEnumerable<ComponentLocation> ParseColumns(string fileName)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> rawData = File.ReadLines(fileName);
            var rows = rawData.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split('\t')).Select(str => new ComponentLocation
                                                                        {
                                                                            ReferenceDesignator = str[0],
                                                                            PartNumber = str[1],
                                                                            xValue = double.Parse(str[2]),
                                                                            yValue = double.Parse(str[3]),
                                                                            Rotation = int.Parse(str[4]),
                                                                            Package = str[5]
                                                                        });
            return rows.ToList();
        }

        public void DoWork(double x, double y, string fileName)
        {
            var components = ParseColumns(fileName);
            //Add values
            foreach (var component in components)
            {
                component.xValue += x;
                component.yValue += y;
            }

            //build file
            StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder();
            //header
            sbData.AppendLine("R.D.\tP.N.\tX\tY\tRot\tPkg");
            //data
            foreach (var component in components)
            {
                sbData.Append(component.ReferenceDesignator).Append('\t');
                sbData.Append(component.PartNumber).Append('\t');
                sbData.AppendFormat("{0:###.###}", component.xValue).Append('\t');
                sbData.AppendFormat("{0:###.###}", component.yValue).Append('\t');
                sbData.Append(component.Rotation).Append('\t');
                sbData.Append(component.Package).Append('\t').AppendLine();
            }
            //write
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, sbData.ToString());

        }

        //call DoWork
        DoWork(10.552, -140.123, @"C:\myfile.txt")
```

Comment: Uploaded solution to drop box.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9676044/ParseColumns.zip
Please accept as answer if this works for you.

Comment: I am testing soon. I will get back to you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file as structured data using ADO.Net. There are ample samples for reading text files with ado.net

Once you get it in structured format in ado dataset, you can traverse and add values. Should be fairly easy.

Here is a good article

[Article Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ConnectODBCText11262005070206AM/ConnectODBCText.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As first step introduce class for single entry, smth obvious like

```cs
 class Entry
    {
      public string Rd { get; private set; }
      public string Pn { get; private set; }
      public double X { get; set; }
      // ... declare other properties

     // Initializes a new instance of the Entry class
     public Entry(string rawData)
     {
         if (rawData == null)
         {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rawData", "Nullable data structure can not be processed");             
         }

         string[] values = rawData.Split('\t');
         if (values == null || values.Count() != 6)
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("rawData", "Invalid data structure can not be processed");
         }

         this.Rd = values[0];
         Double.TryParse(values[2], out this.X);
         // ....
     }
    }
```

After you have build this structure you can easily add any value to X, Y...

**To read a File line by line:**
[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

Read the entire file contents into a `StringBuilder` and try regular expression.